# Can you programmatically send iMessage/SMS without having to press the green up-arrow in iMessage?

Tags: ios, sms, imessage, ios8.2

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to send an iMessage/SMS without having the user press the green up-arrow to SEND.  Is it possible to have an iMessage/SMS just be sent?

Comment: I would certainly hope not. That would be prime for exploitation

Comment: Solid point Alexander, been playing around with code and searching for a more user friendly way to send an iMessage without hoop jumping.

Comment: Imagine if an app decided to go rogue, sending spam, ads, or phishing attacks to contact. It would be like Android D:

Comment: rouge or not, some kind of verification process that you could process that allows a user to send a iMessage just with the press of a single button.  I'm a bit late to the game, but oh well...

Comment: Hmm? I didn't understand any of that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have tried, no.

I can only go as far as setting recipient and content of the message so the user only need to hit the send button to complete the action.

Comment: Thanks Ben - been researching, googling, searching for the most user freindly way to send an iMessage from an app.  Shortest number of steps possible.  It was a reach, but the Stack community seems to come up with the most creative knowledge I've seen and figured - I'd ask.